# Design For Multiple Screens Android

Tags: android, layout, navigation, screen, drawer

I wanted to know that is there a new method to design layouts and scale images for different screen sizes in android.I came across creating 4 different folders (ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi) or using sw600dp,sw720dp,etc.
I want to know which way is the best to do this.
What i am currently stuck on is how much of the screen the navigation drawer must cover when it's open and that would depend from one device to another.

Comment: Take a look @ https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

Answer (score 1):

First, `ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi` was designed for different dpi, and `sw600dp, sw720dp` are dedicated for 7" and 10" screen size (see [google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)). Second, the metrics for `Navigation Drawer` you can find [in official page](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#). Third, I recommend you to choose one of `Navigation Drawer` library from github and use it.